# Create an emulator with a decent size from command line

Tags: android, android-emulator, travis-ci, android-virtual-device

I want to create an ARM API 21 emulator loaded with Google APIs.

Here's how I create the AVD:

```
ANDROID_ABI=google_apis/armeabi-v7a
EMULATOR_VERSION=21
avd --force -n nexus4-emulator -t "Google Inc.:Google APIs:"$EMULATOR_VERSION --abi $ANDROID_ABI --device "Nexus 4" -c 128M
```

And now I start up the emulator with:

```
emulator -avd nexus4-emulator &
```

However, this is what I get: a screen with tiny dimensions (in terms of effective pixels):

[image: Emulator with tiny screen]

How can I change this config so that I have a properly sized screen?

I'm using this to build APKs and run tests on a machine in Travis, by the way, but it's reproducible in my machine (Mac OS X).

Comment: What's interesting (read: highly frustrating) is that two weeks ago this exact config did create a standard Nexus 4 screen. I just hit the key "rebuild in Travis": https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1581166/stackoverflow/build-115-before-after.png

Comment: Also, `android list targets` does list `Nexus 4`, so the `--device` should not be an issue.

Answer (score 24):

### **Update: fix resolution using the new avdmanager**

---

[This](https://github.com/connectbot/connectbot/blob/master/.travis.yml#L51) is a good sample to create an emulator with a decent size using the new [avdmanager](https://github.com/connectbot/connectbot/blob/master/.travis.yml#L51):

```
  - $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/avdmanager create avd --force --name test --package 'system-images;android-22;default;armeabi-v7a' --abi armeabi-v7a --device 'Nexus 4' --sdcard 128M
  - $ANDROID_HOME/emulator/emulator -avd test -skin 768x1280 -no-audio -no-window &
```

There is an [open issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37137534) as [commented here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43614908/1009132) about the unsupported `-s "768x1280"` parameter.

---

### **Previous answer**

---

If you need a nexus 4 style device from commandline, you can try this:

```
android create avd --force -n nexus4-emulator -t "Google Inc.:Google APIs:"$EMULATOR_VERSION --abi $ANDROID_ABI -s "768x1280" --device "Nexus 4" -c 128M
```

Locally is better to use Android Studio.

The next configuration with `device` option for CI builds solves click issues related to screen size:

```
  - echo no | android create avd --force -n test -t $ANDROID_TARGET --abi $ANDROID_ABI --device 'Nexus 4' --sdcard 128M
  - emulator -avd test -no-window -skin 768x1280 &
```

### **Summary:**

---

**Local machine:** the best option is to use Android Studio directly because the Nexus 4 skin seems placed only there and the device definition included in the SDK Tools seems not to be enough to create it; you need to define extra hardware options. I offer a work around below.

**Travis-ci server:** the best option is to speed up it disabling the audio and the window and to use a generic emulator. If you need a Nexus 4 style emulator you can try the same workaround, otherwise, remove the `--device` option and use commands like these:

```
android create avd -f \
    -n "${AVD_NAME:-default_emulator}" \
    -t "${AVD_TARGET:-Google Inc.:Google APIs:21}" \
    -b "${AVD_ABI:-armeabi-v7a}" \
    -g "${AVD_TAG:-google_apis}" \
    -c "${AVD_SDCARD:-128M}"

emulator -avd "${AVD_NAME:-default_emulator}" \
    -no-audio \
    -no-window \
    -debug "${AVD_DEBUG:-avd_config}" &
```

**Note:** on the left side are environment variables you can define in the .travis.yml, otherwise, the right side default values will be used. The last line prints useful and related debug information.

### **Local configuration**

---

The `Nexus 4` device definition is included in

> android-sdk-linux/tools/lib/devices.xml

```
<d:device>
    <d:name>Nexus 4</d:name>
    <d:manufacturer>Google</d:manufacturer>
    <d:hardware>
        <d:screen>
            <d:screen-size>normal</d:screen-size>
            <d:diagonal-length>4.7</d:diagonal-length>
            <d:pixel-density>xhdpi</d:pixel-density>
            <d:screen-ratio>notlong</d:screen-ratio>
            <d:dimensions>
                <d:x-dimension>768</d:x-dimension>
                <d:y-dimension>1280</d:y-dimension>
            </d:dimensions>
            <d:xdpi>320</d:xdpi>
            <d:ydpi>320</d:ydpi>
            <d:touch>
                <d:multitouch>jazz-hands</d:multitouch>
                <d:mechanism>finger</d:mechanism>
                <d:screen-type>capacitive</d:screen-type>
            </d:touch>
        </d:screen>
        <d:networking>
            Wifi
            Bluetooth
            NFC
        </d:networking>
        <d:sensors>
            Accelerometer
            Barometer
            Compass
            GPS
            Gyroscope
            LightSensor
            ProximitySensor
        </d:sensors>
        <d:mic>true</d:mic>
        <d:camera>
            <d:location>back</d:location>
            <d:autofocus>true</d:autofocus>
            <d:flash>true</d:flash>
        </d:camera>
        <d:camera>
            <d:location>front</d:location>
            <d:autofocus>false</d:autofocus>
            <d:flash>false</d:flash>
        </d:camera>
        <d:keyboard>nokeys</d:keyboard>
        <d:nav>nonav</d:nav>
        <d:ram unit="KiB">1953125</d:ram>
        <d:buttons>soft</d:buttons>
        <d:internal-storage unit="KiB">7811891</d:internal-storage>
        <d:removable-storage unit="MiB"></d:removable-storage>
        <d:cpu>Qualcomm Snapdragon S4 Pro</d:cpu>
        <d:gpu>Adreno 320</d:gpu>
        <d:abi>
            armeabi-v7a
            armeabi
        </d:abi>
        <d:dock></d:dock>
        <d:power-type>battery</d:power-type>
    </d:hardware>
    <d:software>
        <d:api-level>16</d:api-level>
        <d:live-wallpaper-support>true</d:live-wallpaper-support>
        <d:bluetooth-profiles></d:bluetooth-profiles>
        <d:gl-version>2.0</d:gl-version>
        <d:gl-extensions>GL_EXT_debug_marker GL_AMD_compressed_ATC_texture
            GL_AMD_performance_monitor GL_AMD_program_binary_Z400 GL_EXT_robustness
            GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888 GL_EXT_texture_type_2_10_10_10_REV GL_NV_fence
            GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture GL_OES_depth_texture GL_OES_depth24
            GL_OES_EGL_image GL_OES_EGL_image_external GL_OES_element_index_uint
            GL_OES_fbo_render_mipmap GL_OES_fragment_precision_high GL_OES_get_program_binary
            GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8 GL_OES_standard_derivatives
            GL_OES_texture_3D GL_OES_texture_float GL_OES_texture_half_float
            GL_OES_texture_half_float_linear GL_OES_texture_npot GL_OES_vertex_half_float
            GL_OES_vertex_type_10_10_10_2 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_QCOM_alpha_test
            GL_QCOM_binning_control GL_QCOM_driver_control GL_QCOM_perfmon_global_mode
            GL_QCOM_extended_get GL_QCOM_extended_get2 GL_QCOM_tiled_rendering
            GL_QCOM_writeonly_rendering GL_EXT_sRGB
        </d:gl-extensions>
        <d:status-bar>true</d:status-bar>
    </d:software>
    <d:state name="Portrait" default="true">
        <d:description>The phone in portrait view</d:description>
        <d:screen-orientation>port</d:screen-orientation>
        <d:keyboard-state>keyssoft</d:keyboard-state>
        <d:nav-state>nonav</d:nav-state>
    </d:state>
    <d:state name="Landscape">
        <d:description>The phone in landscape view</d:description>
        <d:screen-orientation>land</d:screen-orientation>
        <d:keyboard-state>keyssoft</d:keyboard-state>
        <d:nav-state>nonav</d:nav-state>
    </d:state>
</d:device>
```

But the `nexus_4` skin associated and used by android-studio is only here:

> android-studio/plugins/android/lib/device-art-resources

[image]

> android-studio/plugins/android/lib/device-art-resources/device-art.xml

```
  <device id="nexus_4" name="Nexus 4">
    <orientation name="port" size="958,1678" screenPos="94,187" screenSize="768,1280" shadow="port_shadow.png" back="port_back.png" lights="port_fore.png"/>
    <orientation name="land" size="1799,885" screenPos="257,45" screenSize="1280,768" shadow="land_shadow.png" back="land_back.png" lights="land_fore.png"/>
  </device>
```

You don't specify the `--skin` so the default skin `WVGA800` included in the SDK tools is used:

[image]

This skin has associated hardware values in the `hardware.ini` file:

```
# skin-specific hardware values
hw.lcd.density=240
vm.heapSize=48
hw.ramSize=512
```

And the `layout` file includes the next lines:

```
...
device {
    display {
        width   480
        height  800
        ...
```

This is not what you expect when you use the Nexus 4 device definition so I would use directly android-studio locally to create the avd and to use the correct skin.

If you use the command line like you did and try to open it from android-studio, you'll see:

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Local machine solution**

Use Android Studio for both; create and start the emulator.

If you create it using that command, adding a minimum of 200MB as internal storage, you'll solve the screen size issue because android-studio will update and fix the avd using the correct skin.

If you are looking for a command without android-studio intervention, I moved the Nexus 4 skin to the skins folder, added a hardware.ini with the missing properties to it and finally executed the next commands:

```
./android create avd -f \
    -n "${AVD_NAME:-nexus4_emulator}" \
    -t "${AVD_TARGET:-Google Inc.:Google APIs:21}" \
    -b "${AVD_ABI:-armeabi-v7a}" \
    -g "${AVD_TAG:-google_apis}" \
    -s "${AVD_SKIN:-nexus_4}" \
    -d "${AVD_DEVICE:-Nexus 4}" \
    -c "${AVD_SDCARD:-128M}"

./emulator -avd nexus4_emulator &
```

`hardware.ini` content:

```
# skin-specific values
AvdId=nexus4_emulator
avd.ini.displayname=nexus4 emulator
disk.dataPartition.size=200M
hw.camera.back=none
hw.camera.front=none
hw.gpu.enabled=yes
hw.lcd.density=320
hw.ramSize=1024
runtime.network.latency=none
runtime.network.speed=full
runtime.scalefactor=auto
skin.dynamic=yes
snapshot.present=no
vm.heapSize=64
```

This is only an experiment, I don't recommend it, but it seems to work:

[image]

**Note:** I found another issue about the avd name, replaced at some point, I would use `Nexus4_emulator`.

[image]

### **CI configuration**

---

This doesn't solve the Travis-ci case. You would need to copy the `nexus_4` skin or [create your custom skin](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/managing-avds.html#skins) and place it in your project or an accessible location. (**Updated:** I tried this, and it's so slow...)

But you probably don't need an exact Nexus 4 skin, and it's better to use the emulator options like `-no-window`, `-no-audio` etc. to speed up it.

I normally used the `-no-skin` option, but I didn't know the hardware.ini relation, so I'll probably customise my emulator, I need investigate it more. I found that when using the `-no-skin` option locally, the screen size is not correct. See update below.

Another option is to use `--skin 768x1280 -dynamic-skin` when **starting the emulator. (updated: I used this when was creating the AVD but is ignored)** Further information [here](https://github.com/android/platform_external_qemu/blob/master/docs/ANDROID-SKIN-FILES.TXT#L238):

[image]

Alternative custom density from [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/managing-avds-cmdline.html#CustomDensity)

> As an alternative to adjusting the emulator skin configuration, you
>   can use the emulator skin's default density and add the -dpi-device
>   option to the emulator command line when starting the AVD. For
>   example:
>
> `emulator -avd WVGA800 -scale 96dpi -dpi-device 160`

**Update:** tasomaniac commented [here](https://github.com/travis-ci/docs-travis-ci-com/pull/466)

> -no-skin parameter removes the skin. This means that the emulator will be 320x480 pixel widthxheight and 320 density which messes up with
>   most of the tests. The default skin is 480x800 which is fine for most
>   of the cases.
>
> --skin WXGA720 can be used like below to make tests more trusted. This is the best emulator config that is found by default.
>
> `- echo no | android create avd --force -n test -t android-19 --abi armeabi-v7a --skin WXGA720`
>
> 320x480 device with 320 density for Android means that the device is
>   actually 160x240. With this nothing fits in the screen. Non UI related
>   tests in the emulator passes but UI related Espresso tests will fail.
>
> Circle CI also defaults to only -no-audio -no-window

**Update:** the next configuration solved an issue clicking views [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43408479/1009132)

> android.support.test.espresso.PerformException: Error performing
>   'single click' on view 'Animations or transitions are enabled on the
>   target device.

```
  - echo no | android create avd --force -n test -t $ANDROID_TARGET --abi $ANDROID_ABI --device 'Nexus 4' --sdcard 128M
  - emulator -avd test -no-window -skin 768x1280 &
```

Comment: Thank you adding the additional detail here. This answer is really detailed and very good.

Comment: agree, very helpfull

Answer (score 8):

So this is still not solved in late 2017 (Booo Google!).

The minimal change I found to be working is adding `skin.name=1080x1920` or any other desired resolution to the avd's `config.ini` (`~/.android/avd/{avdName}.avd/config.ini`)

Comment: This solved it immediately for me - much simpler solve than above.

Comment: Thanks, this worked once I added `skin.name=1080x1920` and `hw.lcd.density=480`

Answer (score 2):

Here's the relevant bits of my Travis config to have a 480x800 hdpi emulator:

```
language: android
jdk:
  - oraclejdk7

env:
  global:
    # API level and build tools version to build the app. Must stay in sync with the Gradle config
    - ANDROID_API_LEVEL=23
    - ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION=22.0.1

    # ARM processor. If it doesn't load in your Mac computer, use google_apis/x86 instead
    - ANDROID_ABI=google_apis/armeabi-v7a

    # From our tests, the most stable emulator at the moment is API 21
    - EMULATOR_VERSION=21

android:
  components:
    # API level and build tools
    - android-$ANDROID_API_LEVEL
    - build-tools-$ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION

    # System images for the emulator. See http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/android/
    - addon-google_apis-google-$EMULATOR_VERSION
    - sys-img-armeabi-v7a-addon-google_apis-google-$EMULATOR_VERSION

before_script:
  # Create an Android Virtual Device
  - android list device
  - echo no | android create avd --force -n wvga800-emulator -t "Google Inc.:Google APIs:"$EMULATOR_VERSION --abi $ANDROID_ABI -s WVGA800 -c 128M

  # Start the emulator (with no GUI: note the "-no-window")
  - emulator -avd wvga800-emulator -no-window &
```