# Travis CI still failing with Espresso test - Android

Tags: android, continuous-integration, travis-ci, android-espresso

I've got my travis CI set up with espresso instrumental testing for my android library but some test fail on Travis CI while on my local machine (emulator and physical device) everything is okay and all test are passed..

I don't understand why on the server side someone fail, while on the local machine in my ide, with the same script command everything is okay.

Can someone help me out?

Thanks

Comment: did you find a solution ?

Comment: Yes, start using Circle CI instead... https://circleci.com/gh/dvdciri/MultiChoiceRecyclerView/35

Answer (score 0):

Instrumented UI tests using [Espresso Testing Framework](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/testing-support-library/index.html#Espresso) depend on the emulator that you created.

We normally use Android Studio locally, and a different one in CI build servers.

The chosen server is not the reason of the failure, probably [the screen size of the emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32914660/1009132).