# Running Detox Android on Travis CI

Tags: android, react-native, android-emulator, travis-ci, detox

I wanted to know if there was something specific to do to make Detox run in an emulator in Travis CI.

I'm working on a React Native project with Detox configured, and everything is working on my local machine (both iOS and Android). But every time I launch the Android job on the CI it fails... There is no problem with iOS which successfully run the test suite.

I tried different versions of the emulator and finally succeeded to have the emulator boot up (Android 22 and 28 for my tests), but now I always get the following errors that I can't seem to fix when launching the `detox test` command.
The `avdName` name in the detox config file is the same as the one used to create the emulator in the CI so I don't understand the error and I can see in the logs that the emulator is ready...

```
detox[8418] ERROR: [exec.js/EXEC_FAIL, #1] ""/usr/local/android-sdk/tools/emulator" -version" failed with code = 1, stdout and stderr:

detox[8418] ERROR: [exec.js/EXEC_FAIL, #1] emulator: ERROR: No AVD specified. Use '@foo' or '-avd foo' to launch a virtual device named 'foo'

detox[8418] ERROR: [exec.js/EXEC_FAIL, #1] 

detox[8418] ERROR: [EmulatorVersionResolver.js/EMU_BIN_VERSION_DETECT] Could not detect emulator binary version { ChildProcessError: Command failed: "/usr/local/android-sdk/tools/emulator" -version

 `"/usr/local/android-sdk/tools/emulator" -version` (exited with error code 1)

    at callback (/home/travis/build/tsyirvo/react-native-starter/node_modules/child-process-promise/lib/index.js:33:27)

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:301:5)

    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)

    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)

    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)

  name: 'ChildProcessError',

  code: 1,

  childProcess:

   { ChildProcess: { [Function: ChildProcess] super_: [Function] },

     fork: [Function: fork],

     _forkChild: [Function: _forkChild],

     exec: [Function: exec],

     execFile: [Function: execFile],

     spawn: [Function: spawn],

     spawnSync: [Function: spawnSync],

     execFileSync: [Function: execFileSync],

     execSync: [Function: execSync] },

  stdout:

   'emulator: ERROR: No AVD specified. Use \'@foo\' or \'-avd foo\' to launch a virtual device named \'foo\'\n\n',

  stderr: '' }
detox[8418] WARN:  [EmulatorDriver.js/EMU_SKIN_CFG_PATCH] Failed to detect emulator version! (see previous logs)

This leaves Detox unable to tell if it should automatically apply this patch-fix: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47265664/453052, which seems to be needed in emulator versions < 28.

If you feel this is not needed, you can either ignore this message, or otherwise apply the patch manually.

detox[8418] ERROR: Error: No instrumentation runner found on device emulator-5554 for package com.rnstarter
```

My `.travis.yml` looks something like that:

```
env:
  global:
    - NODE_VERSION=10
    - ADB_INSTALL_TIMEOUT=8
    - ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/android-sdk
    - ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/usr/local/android-sdk
    - TOOLS=${ANDROID_HOME}/tools
    - PATH=${ANDROID_HOME}:${ANDROID_HOME}/emulator:${TOOLS}:${TOOLS}/bin:${ANDROID_HOME}/platform-tools:${PATH}

stages:
  - name: e2e_android

jobs:
  include:
    - stage: e2e_android
      language: android
      cache: npm
      android:
        components:
          - tools
          - platform-tools
          - tools
          - build-tools-28.0.3
          - android-28
          - extra-google-m2repository
          - extra-android-m2repository
          - sys-img-x86-android-28
      licenses:
        - 'android-sdk-license-.+'
        - 'android-sdk-preview-license-.+'
        - 'google-gdk-license-.+'
      before_install:
        - yes | sdkmanager "build-tools;28.0.3" >/dev/null 2>&1
        - yes | sdkmanager "platforms;android-28" >/dev/null 2>&1
      install:
        - wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.31.0/nvm.sh -O ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
        - source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
        - nvm install $NODE_VERSION
        - nvm use $NODE_VERSION
        - nvm alias default $NODE_VERSION
        - npm install -g react-native-cli >/dev/null 2>&1
        - npm install -g detox-cli >/dev/null 2>&1
        - npm install >/dev/null 2>&1
      before_script:
        - echo no | android create avd --force -n test -t android-28 --abi default/x86
        - emulator -avd test -no-audio -no-window &
        # - android-wait-for-emulator
        - adb shell input keyevent 82 &
      script:
        - echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p
        - detox build -c android.emu.ci
        - detox test -c android.emu.ci -n test -H --cleanup
```

Did I miss something in the config ?

Thanks !

Comment: Please take a closer look at the logs: This part -- `This leaves Detox unable to tell if it should automatically apply this patch-fix (...) If you feel this is not needed, you can either ignore this message, or otherwise apply the patch manually.` is just a warning. The real error is this:  `detox[8418] ERROR: Error: No instrumentation runner found on device emulator-5554 for package com.rnstarter`

Comment: Have you properly set up a `DetoxTest.java` file on Android? Be sure to follow the setup guide step-by-step (long as it may be...)

Comment: Everything is correctly setup on the Detox side since I can run the tests without issues on my local machine. I'm going to take some time next week to investigate this issue further to see if I didn't miss something